# Adding columns dynamically to ngTable

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have the following `ngTable`, and I want to add columns dynamically:

```
    <table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="showFilter" class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="d in $data" >
                <td ng-repeat="col in cols" title="'col.nm'" 
                      filter="{ col.nm: 'text' }">{{ col.nm }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

$data contains the data itself, but I have the columns definition in a different array:

```
$scope.cols = [ {nm:'col0'}, {nm:'col1'}, {nm:'col2'} ];
```

and $data:

```
$scope.data = [ {col0: "0", col1: "1", col2: "2"} ] ...
```

When I run the code the table is empty without any columns. I tried to look online to see if this is possible but couldn't find an example. Any ideas?

Added [PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/CQqcccEAjtU3DA3Be9Pp?p=preview)

Comment: plis can you put some example in jsfiddle? and.. why u put $data? just use data without $ :S

Comment: don't ask me why, but declaring $scope.data and $data works (I took it from an example) that's how I defined all my ngTables...

Comment: please see the PLUNK I added to the question

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/KQEGq8dzd1hx7dhnQv9w?p=preview - that was exactly what I corrected below when u said it doesnt solve problem.

Comment: You can accept my answer below. I did rollback.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your ng-repeat. You are using Wrong variable syntax
Change this

```
 <tr ng-repeat="d in $data" >
```

to

```
 <tr ng-repeat="d in data" >
```

Comment: 'When I run the code the table is empty without any columns' By changing $data to data will show table. and u need to ng-repeat again in td for dynamic columns.

Answer (score 0):

Lel... i check PLUNK and i see you no declare cols in SCOPE! and how u want take it from html?! xD check change this:

```
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope,NgTableParams) {
          $scope.cols = [ {nm:'col0'}, {nm:'col1'}, {nm:'col2'} ];

          $scope.data = [ 
            { col0: 'User 1', col1: 'Name 1', col2: 'Group 1'},
            { col0: 'User 2', col1: 'Name 2', col2: 'Group 2'}
          ];

          $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({dataset: $scope.data});

});
```

And voila

---

EDIT V2:

Check this html,  i added columns name with one ng-repeat and value in another.

```
 <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <tbody>
        <td ng-repeat="col in cols">{{ col.nm }}</td>
        <tr ng-repeat="u in data">
            <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in u">
              {{value}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this help

Comment: That was a typo, still doesn't work, check the fixed plunk, it shows column names instead of data http://plnkr.co/edit/RRwCH7eJS9zXidSva8s9?p=preview

Comment: uf so ugly and hard, but check it renew

Comment: you have a `td` outside a `tr`

Comment: well, u can set this td in a tr, but u try this solution? this worked well to me

Answer (score -1):

Cols:

```
$scope.cols = [ {nm:'col0'}, {nm:'col1'}, {nm:'col2'} ];
```

Data:

```
$scope.data = [ {col0: "0", col1: "1", col2: "2"} ] ...
```

Template:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtl" ng-app="app">
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <tbody>
        <tr><td ng-repeat="name in names">{{ name.nm }}</td></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="u in data">
          <td ng-repeat="value in u">
            {{value}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Try this.

Comment: I still have the same problem

Comment: Alright, I'll show you example with different approach. You need to use only one object.

Comment: see that I added a plunk to the question

Comment: Please check this plunk, it shows column names instead of data http://plnkr.co/edit/RRwCH7eJS9zXidSva8s9?p=preview

Comment: Yes, as I said before, you need to rebuild your data object. `{{ col.nm }}` - thats what you're showing to user. Check in your data what is `col.nm`.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_tables.asp - see how it is usually done.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/7wXS1Gsj2y9mWFPV40h2?p=preview - it should work the way you need.